# My list prints out the Objects instead of the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a program with a deck of cards, I want to print out the values in my list that I've populated with 52 cards. The Cards have two variables suit and value both is integers.
The problem is that instead of printing out the say ace of spades, that in my case would be 4 of 1 (spades is suit 4, and ace is value 1) it prints the object  **<**main**.Card object at 0x00000221CB653520>**

My code so far:

```
class Card:
def __init__(self, suit, value):
    assert 1 <= suit <= 4 and 1 <= value <= 13
    self.suit = suit
    self.value = value

def show(self):
    return "{} of {}".format(self.suit, self.value)



class CardDeck:
def __init__(self):
    # Constructs the Deck

    self.cards = []
    for s in range(1, 5):
        for v in range(1, 14):
            self.cards.append(Card(s, v))

    CardDeck.shuffle(self)
    for c in self.cards:
        c.show()

def shuffle(self):
    for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
        rnd = random.randint(0, i)
        self.cards[i], self.cards[rnd] = self.cards[rnd], self.cards[i]




Deck = CardDeck()
print(Deck.cards[1:-1]) <----- Should print the full list with both variables, suit and value
```

Comment: In Python, *every value is an object*. In any case, `Deck.cards` is a list of `Card` objects, why *would you expect it not to print a list of card objects*?

Comment: You need "magic" `__str__`  method defined to tell `print` how to print your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the details of your code, if you want the print method when called on an object from some class to do something else than printing the name of the class and the memory location of the object, you need to implement the magic method `__str__(self)` on that class. In your case, I see that you have a method `show` which returns a string representation, but not a method `__str__`. Very likely it will be very similar to your `show` method. You'd probably also want to add such a method to the `CardDeck` class.

By the way, your example seems to be inspired by the book "How to Think like a Computer Scientist". How to use `__str__` as well as the details of this card game example are very well explained in that book.

Answer (score 2):

Printing a value uses `repr`, so you should provide a `__repr__` function for a custom representation:

```py
import random

# list of suits for number to text
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"]

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        assert 1 <= suit <= 4 and 1 <= value <= 13
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.value, suits[self.suit - 1])

class CardDeck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for s in range(1, 5):
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))

        CardDeck.shuffle(self)

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            rnd = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[rnd] = self.cards[rnd], self.cards[i]

Deck = CardDeck()
print(Deck.cards[1:-1])
```

Output:

```
[8 of hearts, 4 of diamonds, 9 of spades, 2 of clubs, 1 of hearts, 3 of spades, 6 of spades, 3 of clubs, 7 of spades, 7 of hearts, 5 of hearts, 12 of clubs, 13 of clubs, 7 of diamonds, 9 of clubs, 1 of spades, 3 of hearts, 2 of hearts, 1 of clubs, 8 of spades, 12 of spades, 11 of diamonds, 3 of diamonds, 9 of hearts, 10 of spades, 5 of spades, 13 of hearts, 2 of diamonds, 5 of clubs, 5 of diamonds, 8 of clubs, 11 of hearts, 2 of spades, 6 of clubs, 7 of clubs, 11 of spades, 4 of hearts, 4 of spades, 9 of diamonds, 6 of diamonds, 12 of hearts, 6 of hearts, 4 of clubs, 10 of clubs, 13 of diamonds, 12 of diamonds, 13 of spades, 11 of clubs, 10 of hearts, 10 of diamonds]
```